# Why this error is showing while writing code

Tags: oracle

Compilation errors for PROCEDURE MTR.MTR_DAILY_MAIL_REPORT_PRC1

Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'EXCELFILE.EXCEL_OPEN' must be declared
Line: 54
Text: Excelfile.Excel_Open(Excel_Data);

Comment: Isn't the error self explanatory?

Comment: Are you sure the error is showing **while** writing the code, and not **after** you wrote the code, when you try to compile it?